# matlab 3D spectogram

Tags: matlab, graphics3d

How to create an application allowing to display a 3D representation of a wave file withtime, amplitude and frequency (3d spectrogram) in matlab.
 NOTE:The ready function of matlab or any other library related with the spectogram are not allowed

Comment: are you allowed to use matlab's fft?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is a spectrogram:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/spectrogram.html